# Make CHtmlView enables activex control download

Tags: mfc, activex, ihtmldocument2

I'm a newbie to CHtmlView of Visual C++ programming. I need to make a web-browser application display website by IHTMLDocument2 interface which will need to download activex control from website and run it automatically. Here is the problem, the application which I have made is running well except the activex control on the website is not running. I have checked the interface of IHTMLDocument2 and also have override OnAmbientProperty to setup the flag to zero when dispid value is equals to DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL, but it still not load activex control on the website which are browsing by using My own web-browser app.

Can anyone tell me which document should I looking for? I'm so confusing about how to setup the security level on my own web-browser application to enable activex.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it work with MFC might be a bit tedious task. You would need to create a custom implementation of `COleControlSite` and `COccManager` for your `CHtmlView`. On the `COleControlSite` object, you'd need to implement `IServiceProvider` and `IInternetSecurityManager`. With `IInternetSecurityManager::ProcessUrlAction` you'd control how ActiveX controls are handled.
Here you can find some implementations of the above:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4805/Advanced-customization-of-WebBrowser-Control-in-Di

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/924/DHTML-User-Interface-Library

http://shareaza-code.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CtrlWeb.cpp

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. Your answer is very useful. I have implemented a new derived class from CHtmlView, and also I have changed the URL policy to URLPOLICY_ALLOW when downloading ActiveX or running ActiveX. Also I have override CreateControlSite method to pass the new COleContainer for IInternetSecurityManager implementation. But It seems ActiveX control is still not running on my own web-browser. I don't know what's wrong, and ProcessUrlAction has been called many times and program should returns the correct value for policy action.

Comment: Is your ActiveX control signed? 
You could also try disabling [FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330729(v=vs.85).aspx#update_restrict).